# How to deal with changed ConfigurationSection-Definition?

Tags: c#, configuration, configurationmanager

I have a Configuration-File that I read with the ConfigurationManager. There are some Sections that I defined by myself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="applicationWideSettingsSection" type="MyTestApp.ApplicationSettings.ApplicationWideSettingsSection, MyTestAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </configSections>
    <applicationWideSettingsSection>
        <pathToSomeFile value="C:\Users\..." />
    </applicationWideSettingsSection>
</configuration>
```

There are new requirements: now I have to store another value in the applicationWideSettingsSection like this:

```
<applicationWideSettingsSection>
    <pathToSomeFile value="C:\Users\..." />
    <pathToSomeOtherFile value="C:\Programs\..." />
</applicationWideSettingsSection>
```

So I change my definition of the applicationWideSettingsSection. If I now run the application with an old config-File it throws an exception on this line:

```
var configSection = _config.GetSection("applicationWideSettingsSection");
```

because there is only the pathToSomeFile-Setting and the other one is missing.
Is there a way to manually add another (default value) to this section?
How would you deal with this??

Thanks in advance, Joerg

Answer (score 1):

Because I didn't want to change my design away from my custom Setting-Types I found a different way:
I set the IsRequired to false so no exception is thrown when the setting is missing. If it's missing I set it to some value from code.
In a different approach I wanted to override some of the Configuration-Section methods but did not get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

> now I have to store another value in the applicationWideSettingsSection

Instead of your custom type `ApplicationWideSettingsSection` you can use a key-value pairs, so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="applicationWideSettingsSection" 
                 type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    </configSections>
    <applicationWideSettingsSection>
        <pathToSomeFile value="C:\Users\..." />
    </applicationWideSettingsSection>
</configuration>
```

This will store 1 or many parameters and allow you to enumerate on the inner parameters. You can also try `DictionarySectionHandler`. I found sample code in this [post](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-custom-configuration-settings-in-net/).

Comment: Seems like I would have to change my design for the settings... But it also seems that there is no other way for this because I will have the chance to add some missing settings afterwards with this kind of solution. Thanks so far, I will try your way and mark as answer as soon as I get it to work... :)

Comment: make sense, gave you +1